# Images working in local but not when pushed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, jpeg

It seems that the ROR precompile of jpeg image is not working.

If I have a look in the console:

`image1-57b4fc128e8ee5872...1500a8cea50.jpg` the image is loaded

But for the jpeg files I got just `image2.jpeg` and the image is not loaded.

Thanks for the help

Comment: where you used this image, In css ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please add some more detail. So we can look into whats causing the issue

Comment: in the html.erb thanks to an helper <%= image_tag "logo_labels/#{label.photo}" %>

Comment: if you want to have a look : http://www.wedressfair.fr/products/562
add look the console, the eko.jpeg is not loaded. Thanks guys

Comment: Sorry, you should include more informations! Thanks

Comment: hard to include more informations, the precompile of jpeg images is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting your image as a `background-image` in css, then be careful to use `ìmage-url` :

```
.your_element {
    background-image: image-url('your_image.jpg');
}
```

instead of

```
.your_element {
    background-image: url('your_image.jpg');
}
```

Using only `url` won't work with Rails asset pipeline (Rails is adding a token before the filename and change it when file change to make the navigator do the request again.

If you're setting your image as an `img` tag in an erb view, then, for the same reason, you should use the `img_tag` helper provided by Rails, and not a classic `<img>` tag

```
img_tag('your_image.jpg')
```

instead of

Hope this helped !